# How to solve the connecting between logstash to aws postgres issue?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, amazon-rds

I've a postgres database rds and I need to query it using logstash through JDBC inputs. I tried most of the solutions such as adding the useSSL=false, etc. But it seems there is an issue. still the logs are not so informative 'maybe bad JDBC string':

> Error: Sequel::DatabaseError: driver.new.connect returned nil: probably bad JDBC connection string
> Exception: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
> Stack: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:228:in `connect' /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:122:in` make_new'
> /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:209:in `assign_connection' /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:139:in` acquire'
> /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:91:in `hold' /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:270:in` synchronize'
> /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:279:in `test_connection' /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:58:in` connect'
> /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.35.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:125:in `connect' /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.0.6/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:114:in` block in jdbc_connect'

and here is the .conf file which I use to connect:

```
  input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:psql://domain.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbtest?useSSL=true"
        jdbc_user => "USERNAME"
        jdbc_password => "PASSWORD"
        jdbc_driver_library => "path/to/postgresql-42.2.16.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from dbtableX"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Comment: Expand `psql` to `postgresql`: Try `jdbc:postgresql://domain.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbtest?useSSL=true` - does that work any better? Docs: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: @AdilB still the same.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can definitely access this Postgres database from the logstash machine via `psql` on the command line?

Comment: @AdilB this is true. Now it works after replacing psql with postgresql. Thanks